# How to acess list of files and folders in a zip file in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve a list of folders and files that are in a zipped file but it returns null

```
File zipDir = new File(strFilePath+".zip");

String[] dirList = zipDir.list();
```

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am making here or is there any other alternative?

Comment: Google is your friend [Working with Zip Files](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class, e.g. like

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(strFilePath + ".zip");
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    System.err.println(entry.getName());
}
```

See also [List Contents Of Zip File Example](http://www.java-examples.com/list-contents-zip-file-example).